# how to repeat function with for loop?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a `pn` sequence and it works. However, when I try I call the function with different inputs in a for-loop, it gives me the same results each time. As if it is not affected by using the for loop. Why?

This is my code:

```
%e.g. noof flip flops 4 ==> 
function[op_seq]=pnseq(a,b,c)
a = 7;
%generator polynomial x4+x+1    ==> 
b = [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 ]
%initial state [1 0 0 0] ==> 
c = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ]
%refere figure to set a relation between tap function and initial state
%
for j= 1:50,
x = a;
tap_ff =b;
int_stat= c;
for i = 1:1: length(int_stat)
    old_stat(i) = int_stat(i);
    gen_pol(i) = tap_ff(i);
end
len = (2 ^x)-1;
gen_pol(i+1)= 1;
gen_l = length(gen_pol);
old_l = length(old_stat);
for i1 = 1: 1:len
    % feed back input genration
    t = 1;
    for i2 = 1:old_l
        if gen_pol(i2)==1
            stat_str(t) = old_stat(gen_l - i2);
            i2 = i2+1;
            t = t+1;
        else
            i2 = i2+1;
        end
    end
    stat_l = length(stat_str);
    feed_ip = stat_str(1);
    for i3 = 1: stat_l-1
        feed_ip = bitxor(feed_ip,stat_str(i3 + 1)); 
        feed_ipmag(i1) = feed_ip;
        i3 = i3+1;
    end
    % shifting elements
    new_stat = feed_ip;
    for i4 = 1:1:old_l
        new_stat(i4+1) = old_stat(i4);
        old_stat(i4)= new_stat(i4);
    end
    op_seq(i1) = new_stat(old_l +1);
end
%op_seq;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing something like:

```
for n = 1:10
  ...
  % set a,b,c for this n
  ...
  op_seq =pnseq(a,b,c)
  ...
end
```

and that you see the same `op_seq` output for each case. This is because you have `a,b,c` as inputs, but you overwrite them at the start of your function. If I remove, or comment out the following lines in your function:

```
a = 7;
b = [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 ]
c = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ]
```

Then I get different results for calling the function with different `a,b,c`. There is nothing random in your function, so the same inputs give the same outputs.

Comment: thanks for replying but what do you mean by( for loop you're referring to must really be outside of your function.).do mean the code wil be this
for j= 1:50
function[op_seq]=pnseq(a,b,c)
 a = 7;
 %generator polynomial x4+x+1    ==> 
 b = [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 ]
% %initial state [1 0 0 0] ==> 
 c = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ]...but it gives me error and how i delete a,b,c from  code it will not wok  they are the inputs and final please clear to me (There is nothing random in your function,so the same inputs give the same outputs.)this sentence do you mean it is not suitable function  generating pn sequence

Comment: @dina see my edited answer. It is important that you set `a,b,c` each time before you call the function. "do you mean it is not suitable function generating pn sequence": no, I'm just saying that you need to vary the inputs. The same inputs give the same outputs.

Comment: sorry but i want to ask for my code i try to build i use pn sequence with length 127 so (a) in the pn code will not change or what? to get different results with same lenght

Comment: @dina: For the same length, `a` will not change, but `b` and/or `c` will change.